# How to read log file for last one hour

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am trying to read last one hour logs available on Linux Server log file. I have tried below commands but it won't work for me.

**Command 1:**

```
    START=`date --date='now-60 minutes' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
    END=`date --date='now' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
    awk "/$START/, /$END/" filepath
```

**Command 2:**

```
   grep "^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" filepath
```

**Command 3:**

```
   awk -vdate=$(date -d "60 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S') \ '$1$2 >= date { print }' filepath
```

Any suggestions/inputs to resolve this query.

**Sample Logs**

```
[01/01/21 22:40:26:088 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:26:166 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:27:360 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:27:475 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:27:668 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:28:211 IST] 0000002a SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 0 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:29:447 IST] 00000040 SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 4 ] ERROR bla bla bla
[01/01/21 22:40:31:328 IST] 00000036 SystemOut     O [WebContainer : 3 ] ERROR bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to compare a date in one format (`%Y-%m-%d`) with the dates in your log file which are a completely different format (`%m/%d/%y`). Try this:

```
awk -v d="$(date --date='now-60 minutes' '+%y%m%d%H%M')" -F'[[/ :]' '($4$2$3$5$6) > d' file
```

I'm assuming that:

1. `01/01` in your example dates is month/day rather than day/month - swap $2 and $3 if I guessed wrong.
2. The times in your input file would always be 2 digits, e.g. `09` rather than `9` - if that's wrong then use `sprintf()` to produce the timestamp for comparison rather than just concatenating the values.
3. You're executing this from the same timezone as the log file dates are in - if that's wrong then set `TZ=...` before running the script.

Comment: DST will mess this up :S

Comment: @kvantour countries that use IST (India and Sri Lanka) don't observe DST.